# Flink 1.12 Could not find any factory for identifier 'kafka' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory' in the classpath

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink job that runs well locally but fails when I try to `flink run` the job on cluster. It basically reads from Kafka, do some transformation, and writes to a sink. The error happens when trying to load data from Kafka via `'connector' = 'kafka'`.

Here is my pom.xml, note `flink-connector-kafka` is included.

```
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>exmple</groupId>
    <artifactId>featurepipelines</artifactId>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Feature Pipelines</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>apache.snapshots</id>
            <name>Apache Development Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <flink.version>1.12.0</flink.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.11</scala.binary.version>
        <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
        <log4j.version>2.12.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala-bridge_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-avro-confluent-registry</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-json</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.bahir</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-connector-redis_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>testing</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <kafka.source.servers>10.111.135.233:9092,10.111.130.11:9092,10.111.130.12:9092</kafka.source.servers>
                <redis.host>10.106.74.22</redis.host>
                <redis.port>19000</redis.port>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- 重命名包, 如果不开启, shade生成的jar包为默认包名, 默认生成的jar会被改名 -->
                            <shadedArtifactAttached>false</shadedArtifactAttached>
                            <shadedClassifierName>Shade</shadedClassifierName>
                            <!-- 过滤掉重复依赖 -->
                            <filters>
                                <filter>
                                    <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                        <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </filter>
                            </filters>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>featurepipelines.generation_ingestion.GenerationIngestionJobRunner</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

This is the full error log, note the sentence `Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factory for identifier 'kafka' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory' in the classpath.`

```
flink run -d -c featurepipelines.generation_ingestion.GenerationIngestionJobRunner -p 1 -yjm 768M -ytm 768M -ys 1 -ynm feat_gen_ingest_user_last_n_clicks -yqu tech_platform -yD metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName=feat_gen_ingest_user_last_n_clicks-metric- -m yarn-cluster /data/code/feat_gen_ingest_user_last_n_clicks/target/featurepipelines-0.1.jar 
submit cmd stdout log:
2021-03-10 20:35:15,015 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                [] - Dynamic Property set: metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName=feat_gen_ingest_user_last_n_clicks-metric-
2021-03-10 20:35:15,015 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                [] - Dynamic Property set: metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName=feat_gen_ingest_user_last_n_clicks-metric-
submit cmd stderr log:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/apache/flink/flink-1.12.0/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/data/apache/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: Unable to create a source for reading table 'default_catalog.default_database.kafka_source'.

Table options are:

'connector'='kafka'
'format'='json'
'json.fail-on-missing-field'='false'
'properties.bootstrap.servers'='10.111.135.233:9092,10.111.130.11:9092,10.111.130.12:9092'
'properties.group.id'='flink-test2'
'topic'='data-report-stat-old-logtype7'
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:330)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:198)
    at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:114)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:743)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:971)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1047)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1047)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create a source for reading table 'default_catalog.default_database.kafka_source'.

Table options are:

'connector'='kafka'
'format'='json'
'json.fail-on-missing-field'='false'
'properties.bootstrap.servers'='10.111.135.233:9092,10.111.130.11:9092,10.111.130.12:9092'
'properties.group.id'='flink-test2'
'topic'='data-report-stat-old-logtype7'
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createTableSource(FactoryUtil.java:125)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.schema.CatalogSourceTable.createDynamicTableSource(CatalogSourceTable.java:265)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.plan.schema.CatalogSourceTable.toRel(CatalogSourceTable.java:100)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.toRel(SqlToRelConverter.java:3585)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertIdentifier(SqlToRelConverter.java:2507)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2144)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2093)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:663)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:644)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3438)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2169)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2105)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertIdentifier(SqlToRelConverter.java:2483)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2144)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2093)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:663)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:644)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3438)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2169)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2105)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertIdentifier(SqlToRelConverter.java:2483)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2144)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2093)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:663)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:644)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3438)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2169)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2093)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:663)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:644)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3438)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2169)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2105)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertIdentifier(SqlToRelConverter.java:2483)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2144)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2093)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertFrom(SqlToRelConverter.java:2050)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelectImpl(SqlToRelConverter.java:663)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertSelect(SqlToRelConverter.java:644)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3438)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:570)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertWith(SqlToRelConverter.java:4277)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQueryRecursive(SqlToRelConverter.java:3452)
    at org.apache.calcite.sql2rel.SqlToRelConverter.convertQuery(SqlToRelConverter.java:570)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.FlinkPlannerImpl.org$apache$flink$table$planner$calcite$FlinkPlannerImpl$$rel(FlinkPlannerImpl.scala:165)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.calcite.FlinkPlannerImpl.rel(FlinkPlannerImpl.scala:157)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.operations.SqlToOperationConverter.toQueryOperation(SqlToOperationConverter.java:823)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.operations.SqlToOperationConverter.convertSqlQuery(SqlToOperationConverter.java:795)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.operations.SqlToOperationConverter.convert(SqlToOperationConverter.java:250)
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.ParserImpl.parse(ParserImpl.java:78)
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.sqlQuery(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:639)
    at featurepipelines.generation_ingestion.GenerationIngestionJobRunner$.run(GenerationIngestionJobRunner.scala:42)
    at featurepipelines.generation_ingestion.GenerationIngestionJobRunner$.main(GenerationIngestionJobRunner.scala:63)
    at featurepipelines.generation_ingestion.GenerationIngestionJobRunner.main(GenerationIngestionJobRunner.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:316)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Cannot discover a connector using option: 'connector'='kafka'
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.enrichNoMatchingConnectorError(FactoryUtil.java:385)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.getDynamicTableFactory(FactoryUtil.java:372)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createTableSource(FactoryUtil.java:118)
    ... 79 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factory for identifier 'kafka' that implements 'org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory' in the classpath.

Available factory identifiers are:

blackhole
datagen
filesystem
print
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.discoverFactory(FactoryUtil.java:245)
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.enrichNoMatchingConnectorError(FactoryUtil.java:382)
    ... 81 more
```

I confirm that `org.apache.flink.table.factories.DynamicTableFactory` is in my classpath locally:

```
> jar vtf target/featurepipelines-0.1.jar | grep DynamicTableFactory 
   579 Wed Dec 02 09:48:44 CST 2020 org/apache/flink/table/factories/DynamicTableFactory$Context.class
   396 Wed Dec 02 09:48:44 CST 2020 org/apache/flink/table/factories/DynamicTableFactory.class
  3794 Wed Dec 02 09:16:50 CST 2020 org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/UpsertKafkaDynamicTableFactory$DecodingFormatWrapper.class
 19234 Wed Dec 02 09:16:50 CST 2020 org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/KafkaDynamicTableFactory.class
 11773 Wed Dec 02 09:16:50 CST 2020 org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/UpsertKafkaDynamicTableFactory.class
  3785 Wed Dec 02 09:16:50 CST 2020 org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/table/UpsertKafkaDynamicTableFactory$EncodingFormatWrapper.class
```

Here is a similar question http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Flink-1-11-2-could-not-create-kafka-table-source-on-EMR-td39512.html but I don't think its answer works for me.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my pom.xml is configured incorrectly.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala-bridge_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Add `<scope>provided</scope>` to each of the dependency fixes the issue.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-streaming-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-clients_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-api-scala-bridge_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner-blink_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Why `<scope>` should be `provided`? Here I quote from [Flink docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/project-configuration.html):

> It is highly recommended keeping the dependencies in scope provided. If they are not set to provided, the best case is that the resulting JAR becomes excessively large, because it also contains all Flink core dependencies. The worst case is that the Flink core dependencies that are added to the application’s jar file clash with some of your own dependency versions (which is normally avoided through inverted classloading).

Comment: As long as you use the same version as the server, provided scope  doesn't really matter. It just happens to not bundle those dependencies as your app