# Flink could not find any jdbc dialect factories that implement 'org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.dialect.JdbcDialectFactory'

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-flink, classpath, sbt-assembly

This [qu/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727738/596167) is the closest to mine, but the solution there does not work for me.

My Flink job runs fine when "sbt built" from Flink dependencies, but fails when I try to submit a assembled fat jar of the same job on an already running Flink cluster (I must eventually submit this way remotely). The error happens when trying to write data using the [Table API](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/connectors/table/jdbc/)  via 'connector' = '**jdbc**' and 'url' = '**jdbc:postgresql:**//..."
and/or driver='org.postgresql.Driver'

(I also tried various combinations of shading, as suggested in other SO posts)

Why can't the complaining calling class in flink.connector.jdbc find the implementation right there in the same package?

```
org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.dialect.psql;
/** Factory for {@link PostgresDialect}. */
@Internal
public class PostgresDialectFactory implements JdbcDialectFactory { ...
```

It happens regardless of whether I use only java or scala (and the corresponding table-api library) (with sbt)

Here is the error trace, which also shows the relevant options fed into Table API, and further below is the sbt file

```
ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.handlers.JarRunHandlerException occurred in REST handler: Could not execute application. \
...
**Caused by**: org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Unable to create a sink for writing table 'default_catalog.default_database.output_table'.
Table options are:
'connector'='jdbc'
'driver'='org.postgresql.Driver'
'password'='******'
'table-name'='spend_report'
'url'='jdbc:postgresql://...'
'username'='qwerty'
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createDynamicTableSink(FactoryUtil.java:262) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
...
**Caused by:** java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find any jdbc dialect factories that implement 'org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.dialect.JdbcDialectFactory' in the classpath.
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.dialect.JdbcDialectLoader.load(JdbcDialectLoader.java:54) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcDynamicTableFactory.validateConfigOptions(JdbcDynamicTableFactory.java:244) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.connector.jdbc.table.JdbcDynamicTableFactory.createDynamicTableSink(JdbcDynamicTableFactory.java:85) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.createDynamicTableSink(FactoryUtil.java:259) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.getTableSink(PlannerBase.scala:434) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translateToRel(PlannerBase.scala:227) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.$anonfun$translate$1(PlannerBase.scala:185) ~[?:?]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:233) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:937) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:937) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1425) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:70) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach$(IterableLike.scala:69) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:233) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:226) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104) ~[flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
    at org.apache.flink.table.planner.delegation.PlannerBase.translate(PlannerBase.scala:185) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.translate(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:1656) ~[flink-table-api-java-uber-1.15.2.jar:1.15.2]
```

build.sbt:

```
    javacOptions in (Compile, compile) ++= Seq("-source", "11", "-target", "11", "-g:lines")
    
    crossPaths := false // drop off Scala suffix from artifact names.
    autoScalaLibrary := false // exclude scala-library from dependencies
    
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-table-api-java" % "1.15.2" % "provided"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-table-planner-loader" % "1.15.2" % "provided"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-jdbc" % "1.15.2"
    
    // libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-runtime" % "1.15.2" % "provided" // for sbt run, which works
    // libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-table-runtime" % "1.15.2" % "provided" // for sbt run
    
    // this works for csv
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-files" % "1.15.2"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-csv" % "1.15.2"
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-clients" % "1.15.2"
    
    // JDBC driver for PostgreSQL
    libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.6.0"
    
    assembly / assemblyMergeStrategy := {
      case "META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.table.factories.Factory" => MergeStrategy.concat
      case "META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.table.factories.TableFactory" => MergeStrategy.concat
      case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
      case x => MergeStrategy.first
    }
```

Contents from Flink Docker image which is the running cluster:

```
@jobmanager:/opt/flink/lib# ls -alh
2022 flink-cep-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 475K Aug 17  2022 flink-connector-files-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  386K Mar 31 13:04 flink-connector-kafka_2.12-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink  93K Aug 17  2022 flink-csv-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 111M Aug 17  2022 flink-dist-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 172K Aug 17  2022 flink-json-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink  21M Aug 17  2022 flink-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink  11M Feb  8  2022 flink-shaded-zookeeper-3.5.9.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  208K Mar 31 13:04 flink-streaming-scala_2.12-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink  15M Aug 17  2022 flink-table-api-java-uber-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink  35M Aug 17  2022 flink-table-planner-loader-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 2.9M Aug 17  2022 flink-table-runtime-1.15.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root  root  4.5M Mar 31 13:05 kafka-clients-2.8.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 204K Jan  4  2022 log4j-1.2-api-2.17.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 295K Jan  4  2022 log4j-api-2.17.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink 1.8M Jan  4  2022 log4j-core-2.17.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 flink flink  24K Jan  4  2022 log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

The content of your `lib` folder doesn't show the Postgres JDBC driver. You need to make sure that the JDBC driver also ends up in the `lib` folder.

Comment: Hi, I don't have access to the `lib` folder (on the remote cluster). How can I make sure it gets there? Am I missing a step referred to in the [classloading docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/ops/debugging/debugging_classloading/) ?